# Reading bytes from bmp file

Tags: c, bmp

How do I read the bytes from a bmp file using C?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a general-purpose skeleton to just load a binary file, and return a pointer to the first byte. This boils down to "fopen() followed by fread()", but is a ... bit more verbose. There's no error-handling, although errors are checked for and I believe this code to be correct. This code will reject empty files (which, by definition, don't contain any data to load anyway).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int file_size(FILE *in, size_t *size)
{
  if(fseek(in, 0, SEEK_END) == 0)
  {
    long len = ftell(in);
    if(len > 0)
    {
      if(fseek(in, 0, SEEK_SET) == 0)
      {
        *size = (size_t) len;
        return 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

static void * load_binary(const char *filename, size_t *size)
{
  FILE *in;
  void *data = NULL;
  size_t len;

  if((in = fopen(filename, "rb")) != NULL)
  {
    if(file_size(in, &len))
    {
      if((data = malloc(len)) != NULL)
      {
        if(fread(data, 1, len, in) == len)
          *size = len;
        else
        {
          free(data);
          data = NULL;
        }
      }
    }
    fclose(in);
  }
  return data;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i;

  for(i = 1; argv[i] != NULL; i++)
  {
    void *image;
    size_t size;

    if((image = load_binary(argv[i], &size)) != NULL)
    {
      printf("Loaded BMP from '%s', size is %u bytes\n", argv[i], (unsigned int) size);
      free(image);
    }
  }
}
```

You can easily add the code to parse the BMP header to this, using links provided in other answers.

Comment: could you add some lines to show how to printf the void * array in hex or char format?

Answer (score 3):

Use fopen and fread as suggested by others. For the format of the bmp header take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#BMP_file_header)

Answer (score 2):

fopen followed by fread

Comment: This answer is technically correct, and don't get me wrong, I agree 100% that it is a funny answer, and that it matches the "style" of the question posed by abhijit, but it is completely against the spirit of Stack Overflow. We are here to provide solutions to people who come seeking help. I may get trouble for saying so, but we should do everything we can to help the OP solve whatever problem they are trying to solve.
I voted for Naveen and Mattthew Flaschen.

Comment: eJames - the answer to the question is indeed fopen followed by fread. Solving the problem further comes down to how to use those functions effectively, or what the on-disk format of a bitmap is, but those are distinct questions of their own. From how the question was asked, it's not clear where the roadblock is, but fopen and fread should open the door to further investigation. I wasn't trying to be funny, it was just the top question when I opened SO, so I chipped in my 2 cents. Sorry you didn't like.

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick [supports BMP](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php).  You can use either of two C APIs, the low-level [MagickCore](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-core.php) or the more high level [Magick Wand](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-wand.php).

Answer (score 0):

make sure this file is not compressed using RLE method. otherwise, you'll have to read from the file and dump into a buffer to reconstruct the image, after reading the header file and knowing it's dimensions.